# R: seq(vector) how does seq(vector) function?

Tags: r

```
vect_1 = c(2,3,6,7,4)

seq(vect_1)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

could someone explain what does seq(vect_1) does?

```
for (v in seq(vect_1))
```

and how would the `for` loop function?

Comment: It sequences/counts the positions, so since you have five positions in `vect_1` it goes from 1-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seq(vector) is the same as seq_along(vector) if the vector has a length greater than 1. That is it returns 1, 2, ..., n where n is the vector's length. Using seq_along is probably clearer.  The help page for seq says:

```
 Typical usages are

 seq(from, to)
 seq(from, to, by= )
 seq(from, to, length.out= )
 seq(along.with= )
 seq(from)
 seq(length.out= )
 
 ...

 The fifth form generates the sequence ‘1, 2, ..., length(from)’
 (as if argument ‘along.with’ had been specified), _unless_ the
 argument is numeric of length 1 when it is interpreted as ‘1:from’
 (even for ‘seq(0)’ for compatibility with S).  Using either
 ‘seq_along’ or ‘seq_len’ is much preferred (unless strict S
 compatibility is essential).
```